# How to not execute parent's :hover on child :hover

Tags: html, css

When the `.post-item` `<div>` is hovered I want to execute some specific styles (change `background-color` and `cursor`) but I don't want this to happen if the `.rating-wrapper` `<div>` is hovered too. This happens because I want the `.rating-wrapper` to do something different than the hover of its parent. Basic question: How to do only child's hover, ignoring the parent's hover

HTML:

```html
<div class="post-item">
    <div class="rating-wrapper">
        <div class="upvote">
            <img src="/images/upvote_arrow.png" alt="upvote" />
        </div>

        <div class="rating"></div>

        <div class="downvote">
            <img src="/images/downvote_arrow.png" alt="downvote" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="owner-data">
        <img src="" alt="" class="owner-avatar" />
        <span class="owner-username"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="creation-date"></span>

    <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can override the cursor, but can't change the parent styles with CSS only. For that, you can use JS: add a class to parent when the child has hovered.

Comment: I believe this is fundamentally not possible using just CSS because it goes against the *cascade*. Parent elements can style children but children cannot style parents.

Comment: Probably best to do this in JS

Comment: @lawrence-witt any ideas how I can do it with js then? Btw I'm using React if that would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to change the style of the parent element based on a pseudo-class of the child element, this isn't *really* possible with CSS alone today.

You can do it with [the `:has()` pseudo-class](https://caniuse.com/css-has) but that is currently not fully supported in Firefox.

```css
#parent {
  background: white;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 2em;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#parent:hover:not(:has(#child:hover)) {
  background: orange;
}

#child {
  background: #aaa;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 2em;
}

#child:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

For a more reliable approach, you should probably look at adding a splash of JavaScript to the mix.

Use mouseenter and mouseleave events to modify the classes of the parent element, then reference the class in your stylesheet.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
const child = document.querySelector('#child');

const enter = event => parent.classList.add('child-hover');
const leave = event => parent.classList.remove('child-hover');

child.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter);
child.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave);
```

```css
#parent {
  background: white;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 2em;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#parent:hover:not(.child-hover) {
  background: orange;
}

#child {
  background: #aaa;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 2em;
}

#child:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS Selector,

```
.post-item>:not(.rating-wrapper):hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

This will select all immediate children of **.post-item** which are not **.rating-wrapper**.

To change the block of the remaining items background color, you can enclose them in another div.

Answer (score -1):

There is a css property called not property.The syntax is like:

```
:not(element) {
// CSS Property}
```

If you want to learn more, please visit this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-exclude-particular-class-name-from-css-selector/

Comment: So what would the selector be? I tried with the `:not` property but I couldn't figure out the selector.

Comment: You should use it like: .post-item:not(:nth-child(whatever you don't want hovered)){//whatever you want .post-item to have}

Comment: The question is about selecting a parent element that is :hovered when a child element isn't :hovered. `:nth-child` would select an element unless it had a particular index among its siblings which is *completely* different.

Answer (score -3):

The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

try:

pointer-events: none

you can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: On which element should I try this?

Comment: .rating-wrapper: {
pointer-events: 'none';
}

Comment: you can also do inline CSS

<div class="rating-wrapper" style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}>

Comment: The problem is I need pointer-events for the hover of rating-wrapper

Comment: to clarify: you want a pointer event on parent element, but you want a different pointer event on child (with none of the parents pointer events)?

Comment: I want to have a pointer event on the parent. The same pointer event won't be run on hover of the child but a different one will be (child's hover)